# pdo statement failing to execute

Tags: php, pdo

i have a pdo block for inserting values into my table as follows

```
try{

        $user = 'root';
        $pass = null;
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=divebay', $user, $pass);

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $desc = $_POST['description'];
        $cond = $_POST['condGroup'];
        $sprice = $_POST['sprice'];
        $iprice = $_POST['iprice'];
        $incprice = $_POST['incprice']; 
        $duration = $_POST['duration'];
        $img = $_POST['img'];


        $owner = $_SESSION['username'];

        $valid = "set";
        $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM auction WHERE ID = :id");
        $stmt2->bindParam(":id", $random, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        while(isset($valid)){
            $random = rand(100000,999999);
            $stmt2->execute();

            if(!$stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                unset($valid);
            }
        }

        $timestamp = time() + ($duration * 24 * 60 * 60);

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO auction(ID, name, owner, holder, sprice, iprice, incprice, etime, img, condition, description)
                      VALUES (:id, :name, :owner, :holder, :sprice, :iprice, :incprice:, :etime, :img, :condition, :description");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $random, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':owner', $owner, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':holder', $owner, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':iprice', $iprice, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':sprice', $sprice, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':incprice', $incprice, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':etime', $timestamp, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':img', $img, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':condition', $condition, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $worked ="yes";
        }

}catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

i cant tell why this statement wont execute, the $worked variable has not been set when it is the script is run. all database column names and datatypes have been checked correct as they are. ive never had a problem with a statement not executing until now. whats wrong? how do i go about debugging this?

Comment: What does `var_dump($stmt)` output?

Comment: You forgot to close the `)` in the 2nd `prepare`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you setup the database connection with error mode exception PDO will throw an exception if something is wrong with your statement. I also see that you are using the MySQL driver for PDO. If you do this you should always disable emulated prepared statements. So I would write you connection as following (note that I have also set the encoding):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=divebay;charset=utf8', $user, $pass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection/12202218#12202218) for more information about this.

Once you have done this you will see that your statement is wrong. You have one missing `)` at the end of the statement:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO auction(ID, name, owner, holder, sprice, iprice, incprice, etime, img, condition, description)
                       VALUES (:id, :name, :owner, :holder, :sprice, :iprice, :incprice:, :etime, :img, :condition, :description)");
                                                                                                                                ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify this line:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO auction(ID, name, owner, holder, sprice, iprice, incprice, etime, img, condition, description)
                      VALUES (:id, :name, :owner, :holder, :sprice, :iprice, :incprice:, :etime, :img, :condition, :description");
```

To

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO auction(ID, name, owner, holder, sprice, iprice, incprice, etime, img, condition, description)
                      VALUES (:id, :name, :owner, :holder, :sprice, :iprice, :incprice:, :etime, :img, :condition, :description)");
```

The difference is the `)` at the end.

And tell me if it works now.